# HTML image doesn't show

Tags: html

I am trying do to a simple HTML page but for some reason some images didn't appear although the src was correct. In order to discover the origin of the problem I tried to insert the images on the body of the HTML document (outside of divs and without the javascript functions I was using to manipulate the images). They also didn't appear! The src is correct and the images are displayed if I open them in the browser (if I type the address of the image in the url bar).

Here is the code:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site2</title>
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
</head>
<body>

<!-- This image appears -->
<img src="images/header.jpg" style="width:100%">

<!-- This image don't -->
<img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="tigre" style="width:100%">

</body>
</html>
```

I can't understand the origin of the problem. I tryed to open the images in a editor and save both of them to see if was a problem of encoding or something like that but the problem persisted, the imagens that appeared before continued to appear and the others continued to not show up.

**EDIT:** If i resized the second image to the same size of the first and save it on a new file it starts to appear although blurry (due to the resizing):

image 1: 1024 x 300

image 2: 850 x 315

The page is just local (I'm not using server programs) and I am using Edge.

Thank you in advance:

Comment: What happens if you remove the `alt` attribute from the second image. Does it still not show?

Comment: If I remove the alt it stops showing the "description of the image". Yes, it still not show

Comment: Can you use the developer tools in Edge and see if that shows a problem? Perhaps it is loading but not displaying?

Comment: Is the console giving any errors? Like 404s ?

Comment: images are missing (404 error)

Comment: Have you tried using the complete image's url/path? You're using a relative path, so the images have to be in a folder named 'images' inside the folder where your script is located. If this is not the case, then the images won't be found and naturally, not shown.

Comment: check if the filepath is okay. They should both be in a folder called "images" which is at the same level as the HTML document whose code you posted. If the HTML page is in a folder next to the images folder, change the filepath in the `img` tag to "../images/img_1.jpg"

Comment: no, the console does not give any errors

Comment: the path to the images is correct, if that was not the case all of the images wouldn't appear but that is not the case, the first image shows but the second don't.

Comment: if I change to "../images/<image name>" the iamge that previously appeared stops appearing.

Answer (score 0):

works and looks ok,

https://jsfiddle.net/hts3wdjx/

```
<!-- This image appears -->
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="width:100%;" />
<!-- This image don't -->
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="tigre" style="width:100%;"/>
```

Comment: the prblem is not my HTML code, if I put the link to my first image on the second image it displays them both. The second image isn't displayed when I use <img src....> but when I open it in the browser it appears.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is `images/`

```html
<body>

<!-- This image appears -->
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBLVUTEfwcBSoQz_SNLw41VH_B76zVbXMgw1FPlQ26cYgC61MyPA" style="width:100%;" />

<!-- This image don't -->
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBLVUTEfwcBSoQz_SNLw41VH_B76zVbXMgw1FPlQ26cYgC61MyPA" alt="tigre" style="width:100%;" />

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean? My problem are the images? They display fine when I put the url of them in the url bar of the browser.